# Scrapy xpath syntax

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

How to I get the text of the paragraphs nested inside the following div using xpath, but stop before Reference? Thank you!

I tried SELECTOR = '//div/text() = "entry-content"/p[1]/text() for the first paragraph, but it didn't work.

```
<div class="entry-content"> == 0
   <div id="dpsp-content-top">...</div>
   <span id="xxx">...</span>
   <h5>...</h5>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <h5>Reference</h5>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should return all the "P" elements before "Reference"

```
//div[@class='entry-content']//h5/strong[contains(text(),'Reference')]/preceding-sibling::p
```

If you need text from the "p" elements, try this,

```
//div[@class='entry-content']//h5/strong[contains(text(),'Reference')]/preceding-sibling::p/text()
```

Comment: What happens in the following case? <h5><strong>Reference</strong></h5>

Answer (score 1):

I think the **xpath** should be like

```
response.xpath('//div[@class='entry-content']/p[1]/text()').extract()
```

Since `<p>` is inside the first `<div>`